# Is there an LR(0) parsing algorithm that handles S/R and R/R conflicts?

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar

If there's conflicts, each entry in an LR(0) action table might have one shift, and several reduce actions; while parsing, I imagine it's possible to try all actions by splitting the stack. Does this way of parsing have a name?

Comment: Your question isn't formulated right. There is an LR parsing algorithm, and LR(0), LR(1), SLR, and LALR(1) parsing tables.

Comment: Thank you, sharth and EJP; I wasn't aware of the distinction. I thought GLR had relied on some properties of LALR(1) (I don't quite understand it, yet.) @sharth, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you both, again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in a [GLR Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser).

Additionally, if you're looking for a parser generator that implements this language, than you might look into [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Simple-GLR-Parsers.html).